# Size of image inside textfield is not resizing

Tags: ios, imageview, uitextfield, icons, leftview

I have a custom text field and i want to place image on its left side, but when ever i am running the app, the size of image is not adjusting , i.e its full scale and not taking the width and height being provided. The code and pictures are attached

ViewController class:(In which text field is present)
import UIKit

class Signup2ViewController: UIViewController {

```
  @IBOutlet weak var Email: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Email.leftViewMode = .always
    let imageview = UIImageView()
    imageview.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 5.0, height: 5.0)
    view.addSubview(imageview)
    let icon = UIImage(named: "c.png")
    imageview.image = icon
    Email.leftView = imageview


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

}

[image: image of app]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the frame for your imageView you need to subclass `UITextField` and override `leftViewRect(forBounds:)`. The code below will result in a 20x20 view offset 10 points from the left and centered vertically.

```
class AwesomeTextField: UITextField {

    override func leftViewRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        let leftViewHeight: CGFloat = 20
        let y = bounds.size.height / 2 - leftViewHeight / 2
        return .init(x: 10, y: y, width: leftViewHeight, height: leftViewHeight)
    }
}
```

To add an imageView to the textField you would do this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: AwesomeTextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "c")
        textField.leftView = imageView
        textField.leftViewMode = .always
    }
}
```

Make sure you set the appropriate class name for the textField in the identity inspector of your storyboard.

Comment: Thanks for that. It helped. I wasnt aware of  'override leftViewRect(forBounds:)'  as i am going through alot of tutorials no one has used it and still it worked. Maybe its a swift 5 thing i guess?

Comment: @AbuBäkr That api has been around for a while actually.